# Как убрать отступы у шапки в css?

Tags: html, css, вёрстка, веб-сайт

Не могу убрать отступы у шапки в css:

[image: отступы по бокам и сверху]

Важно сказать что шапку заполняю не изображением, а цветом:

```css
header {
  background-color: #000000;
  height: 120px;
  margin: 0px;
  padding: 0px;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang=ru>

<head>
  <meta charset=utf-8>
  <title>Pepeland</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="csscode.css">
</head>

<body>
  <header>
  </header>

  <footer>
  </footer>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Все решил самостоятельно.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Отступы нужно убирать не только у `<header>`, но и у `<body>` тоже:

```css
body {
  margin: 0px;
}

header {
  background-color: #000000;
  height: 120px;
  margin: 0px;
  padding: 0px;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang=ru>

<head>
  <meta charset=utf-8>
  <title>Pepeland</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="csscode.css">
</head>

<body>
  <header>
  </header>

  <footer>
  </footer>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: спасибо, я еще смог найти решение с помощью свойства "position: absolute"
а после выравниваем по левому краю и верху с помощью свойств "top" и "left"

Comment: `position: absolute` - для решение конкретных задач, в данном случае грубая ошибка

Answer (score 1):

У многих элементов есть отступы по умолчанию и изнутри и с наружи... Надо обнулять (желательно)

```css
* {
  margin: 0px;
  padding: 0px;
}

header {
  background-color: #000000;
  height: 120px;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang=ru>

<head>
  <meta charset=utf-8>
  <title>Pepeland</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="csscode.css">
</head>

<body>
  <header>
  </header>

  <footer>
  </footer>
</body>

</html>
```